# Varnish on 80, nginx on 8080, on which port to put jenkins?

Tags: nginx, port, varnish, jenkins

On my staging server, I have `Varnish` + `Nginx`. They are on port `80` and `8080`.

**Given that I have to install `jenkins`, on which port I have to bind it ?** (which is usually 8080 but it's already taken)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Configure it to run on any port you like! 81. 8081. Anything really.

Comment: Oh great, didn't know we could change besides 80 and 8080 ;-)

Comment: Well, it seems that Java can't access to port 8081 ... :'( https://gist.github.com/tristanbes/8580f379c1ec4ef42894

Comment: I suggest you post a question with detail on exactly what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried and researched to try and get it to work, and any error messages too.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that Jenkins normally should not be run as root, you can take anything starting from 1024 upwards, because <1024 is reserved for root only.

Comment: I think you meant anything above **1023**. I can bind to port 1024 as an unprivileged user, but not 1023.

Comment: Of course you are right.

Comment: It's always an off-by-one error :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably put it on port 9000, then use Nginx as a reverse proxy to map Jenkins.yourdomain.com to port 9000.

That way you'll get the bonus of being able to let Nginx do SSL too!

Comment: Yeah, that was the plan (without the ssl though) ;-)

Comment: Y U NO SSL?...!

Comment: I like to live dangerously ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As @Drew correctly pointed out, you can pick any port that isn't already used.
However, it is common for Web servers and such (including Web interfaces) to listen on ports 80, 8000 or 8080. If you're setting up a Web interface, as I suspect (I don't know of Jenkins, but I see it listens on port 8080 by default), you might prefer port 8000. There's no real advantage; it's just a common practice.